# How can I add text from textbox.Text to datagridview.CurrentCell when datagridview is filtered C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm not really good at coding and after doing countless research, I cannot figure this one out.

Basically what I want to achieve is to update a specific cell using a textBox. I wrote the following code based on other postings (NOTE:The DataBinding was done using the VS wizard):

```
    int i;

    private void textBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        i = dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex;
    } 

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        myDatabaseDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][5] = textBox.Text;
    }
```

The problem with the above code is that, when I filter dataGridView1 with this code:

```
    private void comboName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTableCollection tables = myDatabaseDataSet.Tables;
        DataView view1 = new DataView(tables[0]);
        BindingSource source1 = new BindingSource();
        source1.DataSource = view1;
        dataGridView1.DataSource = source1;
        source1.Filter = "Name='" + comboName.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
    }
```

The code will update the dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex as expected. The big problem here is that the code under button1_Click does not see the filtering, hence it would write -for example- in row[1] of the unfiltered table rather than in row[1] of the filtered table.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have IDs in your table?

Comment: Yes, I do have a key identifier, but it's not automatically generated, it's based on the order number.

Comment: Are you talking about the index?

Comment: Are there any unique fields for rows other than the index?

Comment: Yes, the order number.

Comment: let me know if the answer i posted solves the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first off, you're gonna have to find a unique column that is unique for every row.
then you can select the dataRow of your dataset based on that like this :

```
int uniqueIDFromDatagrid = (int)dataGridView1.Rows[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.RowIndex].Cells[uniqueIdentifierColumn.Index].Value;
DataRow targetRow = myDataSet.Tables[0].Rows.OfType<DataRow>().First(x => (int)x["uniqueIdentifierColumn"]== uniqueIDFromDatagrid);
```

and then you can update the source on the right row and column like this :

```
targetRow[5] = textBox1.Text;
```

Comment: Hi Niklas, I'm not sure why I'm getting this error: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll

Additional information: Column named Req_Nbr cannot be found." I made sure all the table information was loaded and even double checked the Access Db was intact

Comment: Try passing in indexes instead of writing column name strings like (int)x[4] for example, you probably misstyped the column name somewhere so i guess indexing is easier in your case. Use indexes when selecting from dataGridView as well.

Comment: Hi Niklas, it was kinda late over here. I will try it today and let you know. First I will research for misspellings and then I'll try the code using an index. Thank you for all the suggestions.

Comment: i edited the part of selection from the `dataGridView` try using `ColumnName.Index` like that in the edited code. its much better than using string names as it will be dynamic in terms of location of the column.

Comment: I didn't realize I was using the column name as the "uniqueIdentifierColumn.Index" rather than the "actual" row index (in this case it was Cells[2]. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand your question clearly

Do you mean that the filter doesn't apply when you changed the cell text?

Try adding this to the button click event

```
(myDatabaseDataSet.DataSource as DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = "Name='" + comboName.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
```

Comment: Hi James, what I am trying to accomplish is to have the textbox to update the CurrentCell. The issue I'm encountering is that when the code updates through the textBox, it updates the main table instead of the filtered table.

Answer (score 0):

Base on your code, you create a copy of the original table. Instead of updating the filtered table, you update the original table `myDatabaseDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][5] = textBox.Text;`.

The fix is obvious, I will give you some idea here...

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    myDatabaseDataSet.Tables[0].Rows[i][5] = textBox.Text; // You need to modify this to know which is the correct row to update.
    // Update the filtered table every time you update the main table.
    DataTableCollection tables = myDatabaseDataSet.Tables;
    DataView view1 = new DataView(tables[0]);
    BindingSource source1 = new BindingSource();
    source1.DataSource = view1;
    dataGridView1.DataSource = source1;
    source1.Filter = "Name='" + comboName.Text.Replace("'", "''") + "'";
}
```

Good Luck.

Comment: Hi Leonel and thank you for your reply. I already know what the issue is (code is reading from the main table rather than the filtered table). Unfortunately I have not found a way to write the code in a way to create a filtered table and update it.

Comment: @P.C you can declare the filtered table as a global variable.

Comment: I have limited coding knowledge, do you have a general code that I could tweak to work with mine?